# Change box width to new width on click and back to original on 2nd click, then repeat process

Tags: jquery, html, css, click

Once I click on the box, I want the box to expand to 300x300px. If I click again, I want it to compress to 100 x 100px. So far I've done this.

BUT I want to repeat this clicking action. So if I click on the box again, it will expand to 300 x 300 and if I click again after that it will compress to 100 x 100 and so on....

HTML

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

CSS

```
.box{width: 150px; height: 150px; background:blue;}
```

Jquery

```
$(".box").click(function(){
$(this).height("300px").width("300px");
$(this).click(function() {
    $(this).height("100px").width("100px");
});
```

});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider doing this through CSS; since this is purely a visual effect, it belongs with your CSS and not in your JavaScript.

```
$('.box').click(function () { $(this).toggleClass('big') });
```

CSS:

```
.box{width: 150px; height: 150px; background:blue;}
.box.big{width:300px; height:300px; }
```

Now, you can use CSS transitions to animate the change.

```
.box {
  transition:width 2s, height 2s;
}
```

Here [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4w5Bj/1/).

Comment: I just started learning Jquery and am just playing around. However, your explanation was great and I took a lot more from it then you'd think. Thanks

Comment: Why do you put the transition code in the .box and not the .big element?

Comment: @Jtwa Because I want the *box* to animate, both when I add and *remove* the `big` class. If I remove the `big` class, the transition will no longer apply to the box, so the growth will animate, but the shrinking won't. See: http://jsfiddle.net/4w5Bj/2/

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't make a typo in your question, and you really want it to start at 150x150, then toggle between 100 and 300, I would do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bd7hx/

```
.box {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background:blue;
}

.big {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
}

.small {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

---

```
$(".box").one('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('big').on('click', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('big small');
    });
});
```

The first click will change it from 150 to 300 px high and wide, then from that point, toggle between 100 and 300 px.

Comment: Thank you. Very well explained.

Answer (score 0):

I would set a class on the Click function.

When the user clicks toggle the class.

[jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle between the two states, you're just adding more and more click handlers to the object. Try this instead:

css:

```
.box.big { width: 300px; height: 300px;}
.box.small { width: 150px; height: 150px;}
```

js:

```
$('.box').click(function() {
   if ($(this).hasClass('big')) {
      $(this).addClass('small').removeClass('big');
   } else {
      $(this).addClass('big').removeClass('small');
   }
}
```

Even simpler would be to make one of those two sizes the default style for the boxes, and then just add/remove the "other size" style.

Answer (score 0):

toggleClass is your friend:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('large');
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ackerman/fwyja/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.box').click(function(){
        var dataWidth = $(this).data( 'width' ),
        width = dataWidth !== undefined ? dataWidth : 150;

        if(width < 300) {
           $(this).width('300px').height('300px').data('width', 300);
        }
        else {
          $(this).width('100px').height('100px').data('width', 100);
        }
  }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7zLj2/